# How to express "dare to" in French?

Tags: vocabulaire, usage

Is it correct to use the verb "oser" in the following sentence?

> Mes amis artistes qui sont plus que fiers de leurs talents de peintre
>   jamais osent peindre des portraits.

Comment: Pour un recherche de traduction selon les contextes, le site Linguee http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=anglais&query=dare+to propose des solutions, dont celle que vous avez retenu.

Comment: Although using “oser” in the present tense is totally correct, when used with “ne jamais” I usually see it used in the past, conditional, or future to add a bit of “finality” to the statement (cf: [this not too convincing n-gram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=n%27osent+jamais%2Cn%27oseraient+jamais%2Cn%27oseront+jamais%2Cn%27ont+jamais+os%C3%A9&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cn%27osent%20jamais%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cn%27oseraient%20jamais%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cn%27oseront%20jamais%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cn%27ont%20jamais%20os%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0))

Comment: (For some reason you'll need to "re-click" the blue ('Search Lots of Books') button to see the results of the N-gram linked above)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, *oser* fits well your sentence. However, it  is more appropriate to write it this way:

> Mes amis artistes qui sont plus que fiers de leurs talents de peintre
>   **n'osent jamais**  peindre des portraits.

Answer (score 3):

Oser is good, **but the phrase is incorrect.**

the verb associated with *jamais* (like *pas*, *plus*) must be preceded by *ne*

It should be:

> Mes amis artistes qui sont plus que fiers de leurs talents de peintre
>   **jamais n'osent** peindre des portraits.

It is a little stylistic.

Another form, more usual is this:

> Mes amis artistes qui sont plus que fiers de leurs talents de peintre
>   **n'osent jamais** peindre des portraits.